# How to store JSON data array database if this data come from API in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working on online examination system on laravel when users get exam I want to receive some data from API and store in a database.
Data will be something like this.

```
{
    "user_id": [
        "420"
    ],
    "test_id": [
        "12"
    ],
    "question_id": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
}
```

**My Controller**

```
$fbres       = new Testapp;
$json        = $request->all();
$data        = $json;

$user_id     = $request->user_id;
$question_id = $request->question_id;
$test_id     = $request->test_id;

foreach ($data as $key)
{
    $user_id     = $key['user_id'];
    $test_id     = $key['test_id'];
    $question_id = $key['question_id'];

    $data1 = array(
        array('user_id'=> $user_id, 'question_id'=> $question_id, 'test_id'=> $test_id)
    );

    $fbres::insert($data1);
}
```

Comment: how is the database structure. how should questions store? is there any many to many relationship?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store array in Laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981405/store-array-in-laravel-5-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the array using `json_encode()` php method. and no need to call insert into loop. It's time consuming and may blast your DB.

```
$fbres       = new Testapp;
$json        = $request->all();
$data        = $json;
$data        = $request->ques;
$user_id     = $request->user_id;
$question_id = $request->question_id;
$test_id     = $request->test_id;

$finalData = array();
$blankArr = array();
//Check for array 1-d or 2-d
if(isset($data["user_id"])){
  array_push($blankArr, $data);
}else{
 $blankArr = $data;
}
foreach ($blankArr as $key => $value)
{
    $usr_id     = $value['user_id']['0'];
    $test_id     = $value['test_id']['0'];
    foreach($value['question_id'] as $k => $v){
         $finalData = array('user_id'=> $usr_id, 'question_id'=> $v, 'test_id'=> $test_id);

         $fbres::insert($finalData);
    } 
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Error "Undefined index: user_id" in Loop

Comment: Check in your array user_id is coming or not? If not then use isset() method on $key[''] and let me know is it helping or not?

Comment: When i use print_r($data) it return "Array ( [user_id] => Array ( [0] => 420 ) [test_id] => Array ( [0] => 12 ) [question_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) )"

Comment: @brij try this. I have edited the code and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178678/discussion-between-amku91-and-brij).

Comment: Hey amku91 i need your help

Comment: What kind of help ?

Comment: Now, I want to store answers to the question same as  question_id

Comment: @brij It would be good if you create a new question with whole script whatever you have done till. I ll answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252896/how-to-store-json-multiple-array-data-database-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Convert arrays to json string using json_encode function and then store it

```
$fbres = new Testapp;
$json = $request->all();
$data = $json;

$data = $request->ques;

$user_id = $request->user_id;
$question_id = $request->question_id;
$test_id     = $request->test_id;

 $data1 = array(
        array('user_id'=> json_encode($user_id), 'question_id'=> json_encode($question_id), 'test_id'=> json_encode($test_id))
    );
    $fbres::insert($data1);
```

Comment: It's throw error "Undefined index: user_id" in foreach loop

Comment: why u r using foreach ?
i have updated my answer, check now.