# How to store JSON multiple array data database in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I work on online exam portal after the complete exam I want to store result user detail on the database all data come from API.

**Data look like**

```
{
"user_id": "420",
"test_id": "2",
"question_id": [
    "12",
    "13"
],
"c_ans": [
    "a",
    "b"
],
"ans": [
    "a",
    "b"
]
```

}

My Question_id array data store successfully but not c_ans and an array.

**My Controller**

```
   $fbres       = new Testapp;
    $json        = $request->all();
    $data        = $json;

    $finalData = array();
    $blankArr = array();
    //Check for array 1-d or 2-d
    if(isset($data["user_id"])){
      array_push($blankArr, $data);
    }else{
     $blankArr = $data;
    } 

    foreach ($blankArr as $key => $value)
    {

        $usr_id     = $value['user_id']['0'];
        $test_id    = $value['test_id']['0'];
        $c_ans      = $value['c_ans']['0'];
        $ans        = $value['ans']['0'];



        foreach($value['question_id'] as $k => $v){
             $finalData = array('user_id'=> $usr_id, 'question_id'=> $v, 'test_id'=> $test_id,'c_ans' => $c_ans,'ans'=>$ans);
              $store= $fbres::insert($finalData);
        } 
    }

    if($store)
  {
    return response([
                'Success' => "1",
                'Message' => "Result Submitted Successfull..."
            ]);   
  }
```

**Asnwer stored**
[image: this is issue]

Comment: Can you paste the print_r($value) also in question. It's easy to debug.

Comment: do not use index 0 in foreach loop only for $c_ans and $ans veriable. replace this and try. $c_ans      = $value['c_ans'];
        $ans        = $value['ans'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this as per your data:

```
$fbres       = new Testapp;
    $json        = $request->all();
    $data        = $json;

    $finalData = array();
    $blankArr = array();
    //Check for array 1-d or 2-d
    if(isset($data["user_id"])){
      array_push($blankArr, $data);
    }else{
     $blankArr = $data;
    } 

    foreach ($blankArr as $key => $value)
    {

        $usr_id     = $value['user_id'];
        $test_id    = $value['test_id'];




        foreach($value['question_id'] as $k => $v){
             $c_ans      = $value['c_ans'][$k];
             $ans        = $value['ans'][$k];
             $finalData = array('user_id'=> $usr_id, 'question_id'=> $v, 'test_id'=> $test_id,'c_ans' => $c_ans,'ans'=>$ans);
              $store= $fbres::insert($finalData);
        } 
    }

    if($store)
  {
    return response([
                'Success' => "1",
                'Message' => "Result Submitted Successfull..."
            ]);   
  }
```

Problem is $c_ans, $ans and quest_id have one to one mapping. So retrieve value also one by one.

Hope this will help you.